# Tinymce formats textarea with HTML.. Not showing in DOM?

Tags: jquery

**Edit:** Actually, I just remembered and its mentioned below, the second textarea doesnt update until a specific click function occurs.. I need to adjust the question...

TinyMce formats text... with `<p>` tags, wordpress text "html" textarea gets whatever is inputted into the tinymce, and somehow is formatted with the `<p>` tags.

I want to get the value of the textarea but this would get the value without the appropriate HTML, how is it possible to get the value with the

tags?

Read more below to understand what I mean.

---

**More Detail** *The fiddle alone should show you exactly what I need it's quite simple I would think, but I am adding more detail just to give you an idea what I am truly trying to accomplish so that maybe you see a better way, but honestly I tried to think of everything this seems to be the most simple.*

I am targeting the wordpress tinyMCE `change` event I use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` I `append` the data to my plugin I do this perfectly fine. When user changes to the WordPress text "html" editor I could easily get the `keyup` value from it, but it looses formatting (FYI tinymce adds `<p>` tags). This formatting goes into `the_content()` it outputs into the live frontend with those tags, so this is all about keeping that formatting.

Whats weird to me is the text "html" area maintains that format in their textarea, but in the DOM "firbug inspector" there is just plain text and even when I get the value of that textarea it shows in my plugin as plain text, this causes a problem for me.

So that said my solution is the above, because the text "html" updates the tinyMCE on only when you click the tab though, I can update my plugin if you update the text "html" click the tinyMCE then click the plugin, this is not smooth though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a script is changing the value manually, you need to trigger the change event

```
jQuery('textarea.changing-textarea-focused').keyup(function() {   
    jQuery('textarea.not-focused').val(jQuery(this).val()).change()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xf89K/)

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually want to know this, it can come in handy.... Right as I submitted I realized I needed to change the question, because the hidden textarea doesnt change untill a `.click` function occurs.. I definitely 1+ this because I need to know this :)

Comment: where is the `click` function?

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry can you simulate the case in the fiddle

Comment: Yeah I need to.. the tinymce has two buttons in wordpress the "visual" and the "text" inside the "text" is a textarea when that changes nothing happens to the tinymce.. then when you `click` "visual" somewhere in their code (Cant find how wordpress does it) but they append the value of the textarea to the tinymce.. and visaversa

Comment: Everything I wrote thus far is fine but it is BUGGING me when the tinymce formatted code passes into the "text" textarea it loses format, except somehow the textarea still keeps formatting but shows no trace of it in the DOM?

Comment: I am just going to open another question I messed this one up, because I realized something at the end..

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry let me know the link to the new question

Comment: Ok thanks Arun :) here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928437/textarea-formatting-with-html-but-not-showing-in-the-dom